# Subscript out of bounds error when web scraping

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to web scrape some data, but I am getting the following error message `Error in html_table(nodes_wp)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds` when running

```
###Loading packages###

library(stringr) # build the URL

library(RCurl)

library(haven)

library(readr)

library(plyr)

library(magrittr)

library("rvest")

library("tictoc")

###Web scraping###

TABLE_BIG=as.data.frame(0)

tic()

for(nr in 1:203540){
     link1=paste0("https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:", nr, "-2020:DATA:EN:HTML&src=0&tabId=3")
     webpage=read_html(link1)
     #html info for the table
     nodes_wp=html_nodes(webpage, "div#main.container-fluid div.row div#middle-column.col-md-9.col-md-push-3.col-sm-8.col-sm-push-4 div.main-container div.container-fluid div.row div.col-sm-12 div#noticeDisplayFrame.documentDiv.noBg.overflow-dashboard div#mainContent div#docContent table.data")  
    rs=html_nodes(nodes_wp, "tr")
     tab=html_table(nodes_wp)[[1]]
     tab_transp=as.data.frame(t(tab$X3))
     names(tab_transp)=tab$X1
     tab_transp$ID=paste0(nr,"-2020")
     #STORE INFO
     TABLE_BIG=rbind.fill(TABLE_BIG,tab_transp )
     #count time
     if(nr%in%seq(5,300000, by=500))
    
    toc()
     tic()    } #ending loop

toc()

###Exporting to CSV###

`write_csv(TABLE_BIG, "C:TED_202001-202004")`
```

Being unfamiliar with R, I do not understand how to solve this issue.

Would someone have suggestions?

Comment: `list()[[1]]` reports that same error. Have you checked your intermediate values to see if `nodes_wp` is not empty?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it's indeed what is happening -- `nodes_wp` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by empty nodes, which cannot be subsettet and thus throw the error. If you do not need to keep track of which nodes are empty, you can just add an `if` condition to check if the `rs` variable is empty and if it is break the loop and start with the next iteration. The following code does this:

```
TABLE_BIG=as.data.frame(0)

tic()

for(nr in 1:203540){
  link1=paste0("https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:", nr, "-2020:DATA:EN:HTML&src=0&tabId=3")
  webpage=read_html(link1)
  #html info for the table
  nodes_wp=html_nodes(webpage, "div#main.container-fluid div.row div#middle-column.col-md-9.col-md-push-3.col-sm-8.col-sm-push-4 div.main-container div.container-fluid div.row div.col-sm-12 div#noticeDisplayFrame.documentDiv.noBg.overflow-dashboard div#mainContent div#docContent table.data")  
  rs=html_nodes(nodes_wp, "tr")
  if (length(rs) == 0) next #start with next iteration if rs is empty
  tab=html_table(nodes_wp)[[1]]
  tab_transp=as.data.frame(t(tab$X3))
  names(tab_transp)=tab$X1
  tab_transp$ID=paste0(nr,"-2020")
  #STORE INFO
  if (nr == 282) print(nr)
  TABLE_BIG=rbind.fill(TABLE_BIG,tab_transp )
  #count time
  if(nr%in%seq(5,300000, by=500))

    toc()
  tic()    } #ending loop

toc()
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It does partly, but the code breaks at some point. The first time I ran your code, I received the error message:

`Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 500.`

And the second time I tried to run it:

`Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Failed to connect to ted.europa.eu port 443: Timed out`

A possible explanation is that the website temporarily banishes me because I am scrapping too much information via R? 

Thanks again for your help.